# Quadrangle that is not a parallelogram, but has congruent opposites and 2 parallel sides

Tags: geometry

Does there exist a quadrangle $ABCD$ that is not a parallelogram, but opposite sides are congruent and $AB$ is parallel to $CD$?

My initial thought was something of a bowtie shape or a trapezoid, but neither of these work.

Comment: What are your own attempts at answering the question?

Comment: i thought initially it could be a bowtie or a trapezoid, but i'm not sure these work for congruent opposite sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

[image]

Sorry the letters are wrong, based on your question, but you get the idea.

NOTE: One definition of a parallelogram is a quadrilateral whose opposite sides are congruent and parallel, so the answer cannot be a quadrilateral.